# How do I know when I should bend a verb?

Tags: verbes

I have always this issue. I don't know when I should bend a verb.
It's easy when I first use the keyword "I, me, you, we" etc, but when it comes to sentences like this:

```
but its tools for identifying...
```

For me, the word `identify` in french is `identifier`. Here it's an `-er` verb and I talking about `tool`**s** and not a single tool.

So the verb `identifier` would be `identifient`, but that so

```
mais ses outils pour identifient....
```

That sounds wrong. So in this case, how do I know that I should bend the verb `identifier` or use it as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Identifying*** is the present participle of the verb *to identify*. The verb is used as such, it is not conjugated to any person, so there is no personal pronoun, no subject. The tools are not a subject. The sentence only says that these tools are designed to identify something, but there is no action going on.

The French present participle is much less used than its English counterpart which is often translated by the French infinitive, an unconjugated form of a verb as well, e.g.:

> **Smoking** is forbidden -> ***Fumer** est interdit*

so the right form to use in your case is the infinitive:

> mais ses outils pour **identifier** [...]

Comment: So when a verb is not connected to a person, or persons, then I should not bend the verb?

Comment: For example `quand l’identification de système arrive dans le monde par Ho- et Kalman, qui étaient `. Here I bending `être` to `étaient` because I talking about two persons or more, who `was`....

Comment: The relative pronoun *qui* is the subject of the verb *être* here. The verb is conjugated at the second person plural because it refers to Ho and Kalman, two person indeed. By the way, I say "conjugate" or "inflect" a verb, not "bend".

Comment: Thank you so much.